# Unable to move on next Activity from fragment by using Intent in Volley Library

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, android-volley

I am trying to login by using volley library. I have used SharedPrefrences to store User name,email,mobile. When I am using correct mobile no. and password. Toast is generating to login successful but not able to move Login Fragment to Dashboard Activity.

Here is the Code of login method

```
private void login(String login_url, final String getLoginMob, final String getLoginPwd) {

    //Progress Dialog code
    final Dialog dialog =new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading_dialog);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    StringRequest postrequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, login_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            dialog.dismiss();

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                if (jsonObject.getBoolean("success") == true ) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),jsonObject.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    JSONObject jsonObjectInfo=jsonObject.getJSONObject("User");
                    sharedPrefrence_main.setName(jsonObjectInfo.getString("name"));
                    sharedPrefrence_main.setEmail(jsonObjectInfo.getString("email"));
                    sharedPrefrence_main.setMobile_no(jsonObjectInfo.getString("mobile"));

                    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), Dashboard.class);
                    startActivity(intent);


                } else if (jsonObject.getBoolean("success") == false) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Entries are wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> param=new HashMap<String, String>();
            param.put("mobile_email", getLoginMob);
            param.put("password", getLoginPwd);
            return param;

        }
    };

    int socketTimeout = 30000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    postrequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    queue.add(postrequest);

}
```

**JSON Response**

{"success":"true","message":"Login Sucessfully","User":[{"name":"satishkanaujiya ","email":"*****@gmail.com","mobile":"901589****"}]}

Comment: You should do it with getActivity().startActivity(intent)

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman I tried but did not helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an array and I was treating it as objects. Finally I corrected my mistakes by following codes.

```
                JSONArray jsonArrays=jsonObject.getJSONArray("User");
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArrays.length();i++){
                 JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArrays.getJSONObject(i);
                    sharedPrefrence_main.setName(jsonObject1.getString("name"));
                    sharedPrefrence_main.setEmail(jsonObject1.getString("email"));
                    sharedPrefrence_main.setMobile_no(jsonObject1.getString("mobile"));

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Type your Intent code here
        }
    });
```

OR

Use LocalBraodcastManager:
Use this link: [how to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)